# Amazon S3 File Encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I am developing a project which requires video file encryption. I am familiar with AWS S3 so I have decided to use the same. I found the link [Reference Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html)

Which says we need to provide our encryption key to to encrypt the data and AWS takes care of the data writing and we can access the file again by passing the same encryption key.

I want to know from where should I generate the encryption key?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the "customer-provided encryption keys" section. In that case, you provide the encryption key.

If you don't want to, or know how to, manage your own keys, you should use [S3-managed encryption keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html) or (even better) [KMS-managed encryption keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingKMSEncryption.html).

For even more safety, [client-side encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/client-side-using-kms-java.html) is nice.